# Access prop outside of class in React when calling Higher Order Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I am trying to use a Higher Order Component(HOC) pattern to reuse some code that connects to state and uses the Redux Form formValueSelector method.

formValueSelector requires a sting referencing the name of the form.  I would like to set this dynamically and be able to use this HOC whenever I need the values of items.  I use the item values to make calculations.

In the code below the HOC is passed the component and a string.  I would like to set this to the prop formName that has been passed in from the parent(form).

I am new to the HOC pattern so any tips would be most appreciated.

HOC

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { formValueSelector } from 'redux-form';

function FormItemsValueSelectorHOC(FormElement, formName) {
  const selector = formValueSelector(formName);
  @connect(state => {
    console.log(state);
    const items = selector(state, 'items');
    return {
      items
    };
  }, null)
  class Base extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <FormElement {...this.props} />
      );
    }
  }
  return Base;
}
export default FormItemsValueSelectorHOC;
```

Wrapped Component

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Field } from 'redux-form';
import formItemsValueSelectorHOC from '../Utilities/FormItemsValueSelectorHOC';

const renderField = ({ placeholder, input, type}) => {
  return (
    <input
      {...input}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      type={type}
    />
  );
};

class StatementLineItemDesktop extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    items: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    index: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    item: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    fields: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    formName: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  };

  calculateLineTotal(items, index) {
    let unitPrice = '0';
    let quantity = '0';
    let lineTotal = '0.00';
    if (items) {
      if (items[index].price) {
        unitPrice = items[index].price.amountInCents;
      }
      quantity = items[index].quantity;
    }
    if (unitPrice && quantity) {
      lineTotal = unitPrice * quantity;
      lineTotal = Number(Math.round(lineTotal+'e2')+'e-2').toFixed(2); 
    }
    return <input value={lineTotal} readOnly placeholder="0.00" />;
  }

  render() {
    const { items, index, item, fields, formName} = this.props;
    return (
      <tr id={`item-row-${index}`} key={index} className="desktop-only">
        <td>
          <Field
            name={`${item}.text`}
            type="text"
            component={renderField}
            placeholder="Description"
          />
        </td>
        <td>
          <Field
            name={`${item}.quantity`}
            type="text"
            component={renderField}
            placeholder="0.00"
          />
        </td>
        <td>
          <Field
            name={`${item}.price.amountInCents`}
            type="text"
            component={renderField}
            placeholder="0.00"
          />
        </td>
        <td className="last-col">
          <Field
            name={`${item}.price.taxInclusive`}
            type="hidden"
            component="input"
          />
          {::this.calculateLineTotal(items, index)}
          <a
            className="remove-icon"
            onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}
          >
            <span className="icon icon-bridge_close" />
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
}

export default formItemsValueSelectorHOC(StatementLineItemDesktop, 'editQuote');
```

Comment: Not sure if it's clear to me, but have you thought of exporting just the react component `StatementLineItemsDesktop` class and importing this React component along with the `formItemsValueSelectorHOC` function in the file where your parent component is declared so you can call this HOC in your parent's `render()` method using `this.props.formName` as the 2nd argument?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TLDR: use `ownProps` parameter

Draft of what you should do

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { formValueSelector } from 'redux-form';

function FormItemsValueSelectorHOC(FormElement) {
  @connect((state, ownProps) => {
    const formName = ownProps.formName;
    const selector = formValueSelector(formName);
    const items = selector(state, 'items');
    return {
      items
    };
  }, null)
  class Base extends Component {
    render() {
      // Now in here you should omit `formName` from the props you are
      // passing to your Form Element since it's not used overthere
      return (
        <FormElement {...this.props} />
      );
    }
  }
  return Base;
}
export default FormItemsValueSelectorHOC;
```

And this will be the way you will create your connected component

```
formItemsValueSelectorHOC(StatementLineItemDesktop);
```

And this will be the way you use it

```
<ConnectedStatementLineItemDesktop formName={"editQuote"} />
```

Let me explain a bit more how this work

The thing that you were missing is React-Redux API, you should probably explore it more because it already contemplates a lot of this use cases

So, React-Redux's `connect` function's first parameter is called `mapStateToProps`.

This is its signature:

```
mapStateToProps(state, [ownProps]): stateProps
```

The thing that I want to remark is the `ownProps` parameter.

`ownProps` contains all the props that are passed to your connected component.

Just for clarification, you have these components

- Regular Component: i.e. `StatementLineItemDesktop` and `Base`
- Connected Component: i.e. `ConnectedBase = connect(mapStateToProps)(Base)`

So, from this information, your HOC function called `FormItemsValueSelectorHOC` returns a variation of `ConnectedBase`.

So, whatever props you pass to `ConnectedBase` or whatever component it's returned from `FormItemsValueSelectorHOC` you can access them from `ownProps`

BTW, in your particular case, this is your mapStateToProps

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  const formName = ownProps.formName;
  const selector = formValueSelector(formName);
  const items = selector(state, 'items');
  return {
    items
  };
}
```

The thing to Note is that `connect` is also an HOC, so it's logically to think that most of the things you do with normal components you will also be able to do with connected Components, I would suggest for you to read the `connect` source, it's not long nor difficult so you can probably explore and comprehend more of this answer.

I hope this helped.

Comment: Well answered!!

Comment: Thanks for this. This helps solve my problem on how I can dynamically set the formName and form field names.