# How to access prop outside of class while calling higher order component such that Higher order component will be reusable

Tags: reactjs, react-native, higher-order-functions, higher-order-components

I have created higher order component to render loader, if data is not available. component named as **Loader** is higher order component. and component named as **ContactList** calls the Higher order component.
My code for ContactList component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import Loader from './hoc/Loader.js';

class ContactList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    }
  }

 render() {
   return (
     <div className="App">
       {
        this.props.contacts.map((contact, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <p>{contact.name}</p>
          </div>
        ))
      }
    </div>
   );
  }
}

export default Loader(this.props.contacts)(ContactList);
```

code for Loader(HOC) component -

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Loader.css';

const Loader = (propName) => (WrappedComponent) => {
    return class Loader extends Component {
        isEmpty(prop) {
            return (
                prop === null ||
                prop === undefined ||
                (prop.hasOwnProperty('length') && prop.length === 0) ||
                (prop.constructor === Object.keys(prop).length === 0)
            );
        }
        render() {
            return this.isEmpty(propName) ? <div className="loader"></div> : <WrappedComponent {...this.props}/>
        }
    }
}

export default Loader;
```

But i am getting this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contacts' of undefined
>   as props are not accessible outside of class.

I have tried many solutions -

1) [one of tried solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39886189/access-prop-outside-of-class-in-react-when-calling-higher-order-component)

2) If I change my export statement to `export default Loader(ContactList)`, then this works fine but the loader component is no more reusable

Comment: We can pass the contacts has a prop to ContactList right?

Comment: yes, contactList component is getting contacts array via props. and now i want to send it to Higher order component

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
export default Loader(this.props.contacts)(ContactList);
```

You're trying to access props outside of class. It is impossible to access them out of your ContactList class.

**EDIT**

If you need to show loader, depending on **contacts** array, you don't need to use HOC. Just use Loader inside of your template:

```
<Loader contacts={this.props.contacts}>
      {
        this.props.contacts.map((contact, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <p>{contact.name}</p>
          </div>
        ))
      }
</Loader>
```

*Note, that in that case, you have to make your Loader just a component, not HOC*.

Here the example of such case:

```
class Loader extends React.Component {
  render(){
    const {values} = this.props;
    if (values.length) {
       return this.props.children;
    }
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }
 }
```

And use it in ContactListComponent:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import Loader from './hoc/Loader.js';

class ContactList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    }
  }

 render() {
   return (
     <div className="App">
       <Loader values={this.props.contacts}>
       {
        this.props.contacts.map((contact, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <p>{contact.name}</p>
          </div>
        ))
      }
      </Loader>
    </div>
   );
  }
}

export default ContactList;
```

The Loader component just example, use your own Loader. 
As I've said, there are no need to use HOC. Anyway, your Loader component will be reusable, because you can use it in different component also. Hope this helps

Comment: @Azamat Zorkanov, I understand that i am accessing props outside of class so this error came. But I need solution for this. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: How my Loader component could be able to find weather data is available or not

Comment: If you will pass data into Loader, then it will find about data existense through props

Comment: @Azamat Zorkanov, yes, I can call HOC as `export default Loader(ContactList);`  this will work but then the Loader component will not be reusable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be the way you're trying to access props:

```
export default Loader(this.props.contacts /* <-- this is incorrect */ )(ContactList);
```

Rethink the situation - what is it you're trying to achieve? What does `this` mean in the context of your module?

Usually when using HOC's, you will find that a pattern similar to this emerges:

```
export default Loader(ContactList);
```

Which (depending on the implementation of `Loader`) would then allow you to import that component (ie LoaderContactList) and pass props "through" `Loader` down to the inner `ContactList` as follows:

```
<LoaderContactList contacts={ [ 'bob', 'joe', 'mary' ] } />
```

Hopefully this offers some clarification.

#### Update illustrating HOF/HOC concept

To illustrate the HOC concept described in my answer, see the following:

```
export function(InnerComponent) { // This is the higher-order-function to export (ie Loader)

    return class OuterComponent extends Component { // This is the higer-order-component

        render() {
            /* To illustrate the possiblitiy of reusable code via HOC's, 
               this HOC responds to an generic 'isBusy' prop by returning 
               a loading message if truthy */
            if(this.props.isBusy) {
                return <p>Loading</p>
            }

            /*
            Otherwise, the inner component that you pass to the higer- 
            order-function is rendered. The "pass through" concept I 
            discuss is shown here. Notice how all props from the 
            OuterComponent are passed through to the InnerComponent (ie 
            ContactList) 
            */
            return <InnerComponent { ...this.props } />
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, this works but i cannot make the component reusable by this method

Comment: what will be the value for this.props.isBusy?

Comment: thank you for your response. I want to know how can i send isBusy from the component where we are calling HOC. and this should be in terms of props so that it will detect changes in data

Comment: will it be able to detect change in contacts array ? as initially it is empty and after api response it has value in it

Comment: You could implement logic that detects changes in data internally however because changes in your array are immediately rendered in your Contacts component, then that makes this application of HOC redundant. If you are doing asynchronous loading of contact data then you could set isBusy to true when ever contact data is loading, thus achieving your goals for reusable componentry

Comment: I will be right it as `export default Loader(this.props.isBusy)(ContactList)`. Do I ?

Answer (score 0):

export default Loader(this.props.contacts)(ContactList);

this is wrong , you have to set one let variable out side of class and set it inside of class , then call it there

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this

**HOC :**

```
const Loader = (props) => (WrappedComponent) => (moreProps) => {
const ContactList = props.ContactList;
 return (
   <Wrapper>
     <Container>
       <WrappedComponent {...moreProps} />
     </Container>
   </Wrapper>
 )
}
```

Now you can use it like this

```
export default Loader({ [ 'Praveen', 'Hari', 'Swamy' ] })(ContactList)
```

Comment: thanks @Praveen Rao Chavan.G . This will work but the Loader component will not be reusable

Comment: So you mean Loader is a HOC which you will be using not only for contacts but for other types of data also, right?

Comment: yes, I want to make it reusable so that i can use it anywhere in my app for the different components

Answer (score 0):

I changed the way of passing and accessing data. My changed code is as follow -

**Code for ContactList component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import Loader from './hoc/Loader.js';

class ContactList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {
          this.props.contacts.map((contact, index) => (
            <div key={index}>
              <p>{contact.name}</p>
            </div>
          ))
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Loader('contacts')(ContactList);
```

**Code for Loader (either Higher order component) -**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Loader.css';

const Loader = (propName) => (WrappedComponent) => {
    return class Loader extends Component {
        isEmpty(prop) {
            return (
                prop === null ||
                prop === undefined ||
                (prop.hasOwnProperty('length') && prop.length === 0) ||
                (prop.constructor === Object.keys(prop).length === 0)
            );
        }
        render() {
            return this.isEmpty(this.props[propName]) ? <div className="loader"></div> : <WrappedComponent {...this.props}/>
        }
    }
}

export default Loader;
```

Comment: suppose you have this.props.anyName, pass it as `export default Loader('anyName')(ContactList)` and access it as `this.props[propName]`. In this way the HOC remains to be reusable